# Kotlin native interop linker could not find framework

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to use cocoapods framework in Kotlin Multiplatform project.
So I

- added framework to Pods file.
- ran pod install.
- created `.def` file
- added `cinterop` config in `build.gradle`

`./gradlew cinteropFirebaseIos` runs successfully. It generates `.klib` so I can see classes in kotlin code.
But when I'm trying to run iOS app build fails with message:

> Showing Recent Messages
>
> > Task :app:linkDebugFrameworkIos
>
> ld: framework not found FirebaseDatabase
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld invocation reported errors

Here is my config in `build.gradle`

```
    fromPreset(presets.iosX64, 'ios') {
        compilations.main {
            outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
            cinterops {
                firebase {
                    def proj = "${System.getProperty("user.home")}/Projects/kmpp"
                    def pods = "${proj}/iosApp/Pods"

                    defFile "${proj}/app/src/iosMain/c_interop/libfirebase.def"

                    includeDirs "${pods}/Firebase",
                            "${pods}/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources",
                            "${pods}/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/FirebaseAnalytics.framework/Headers"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my `.def` file:

```
language = Objective-C
headers = /Users/oleg/Projects/klug/crckalculator/iosApp/Pods/FirebaseCore/Firebase/Core/Public/FIRApp.h /Users/oleg/Projects/klug/crckalculator/iosApp/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/Firebase/Database/Public/FIRDatabase.h /Users/oleg/Projects/klug/crckalculator/iosApp/Pods/FirebaseCore/Firebase/Core/Public/FirebaseCore.h

compilerOpts = -framework FirebaseDatabase
linkerOpts = -framework FirebaseDatabase
```

[image]

How can I figure out what is wrong ? Did I miss something in `.def` file ? In `build.gradle` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problematic moments here:

- full paths to C headers in `.def` file are usually not desirable, instead passing `includeDirs` to Firebase installation, like in https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/c7c566ce0f12221088a8908b6dc8e116c56a931b/samples/gtk/build.gradle#L22 would be helpful
- linking problem comes from the similar issue - linker just got no idea where to look for framework libraries, so passing to `compilations.main.linkerOpts` smth like `-F /Users/oleg/Projects/klug/crckalculator/iosApp/Pods/FirebaseCore/` shall help, see for example https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/c7c566ce0f12221088a8908b6dc8e116c56a931b/samples/videoplayer/build.gradle#L15

Comment: Thanks @Nikolay. Regarding full path to headers it's quite obvious, I've been trying to do this but it could not resolve imports. For instance `Firebase.h` starts with `#import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>` but `FirebaseCore.h` placed under `iosApp/Pods/FirebaseCore/Firebase/Core/Public/` folder.

Comment: Another quite strange thing is that `FIRAnalyticsConnector.framework`, `FirebaseAnalytics.framework`, `FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework`, `FirebaseInstanceID.framework` and `GoogleAppMeasurement.framework` in my `Pods` folder although I did not install these pods. `FirebaseDatabase.framework` I found in `/Users/oleg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iosApp-dhmxgbkvemesnaamasxaqqyuqyox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseDatabase/` folder. Now when I'm specifying this framework I'm getting some `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:` errors (there are quite a few of them).

Comment: BTW there are `linkerOpts` in both `.gradle` and `.def` files. Are they the same ?

Comment: One more question: What about transitive dependencies ? Firebase consists of few libs/frameworks like Core, Database, Firestore, Messaging etc. They depend on each other. Is it enough to specify one of them I'm using ? Or should I specify all of them ?

Comment: Linker options from .def and Gradle pluginare concatenated essentially.